# How can I access a public static member of a Java class from ColdFusion?

Tags: java, coldfusion

How can I access a public static member of a Java class from ColdFusion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You run the createObject but don't call the "init" before running the static method. For example:

```
<cfset systemObject = createObject("java", "java.lang.System") />
<cfoutput>#systemObject.currentTimeMillis()#</cfoutput>
```

In this case "currentTimeMillis()" is a static method of the System class.

Answer (score 1):

I would also mention that the class has to be in CF's classpath.